# Rails 4.0 way to unscope the default_scope at another scope definition (with_exclusive_scope depreciated)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, scope

This maybe a really simple question but I have been trying to understand how to do it in Rails 4.0. Basically, it's a basic user and post app with `User` has_many `Post`. Moreover, in each post there is a boolean value of `:images_to_process`. What it does is to indicate if all the images belongs to this `Post` has been processed by delayed_jobs. Incomplete post should not be displayed to avoid image loading problems. Here's the code which works for Rails 3:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope { where(is_deleted: false, images_to_process: 0) }
  scope :everything, -> user {with_exclusive_scope { where(is_deleted: false, user_id: user) }}
```

As you may have noticed, `with_exclusive_scope` is depreciated in Rails 4. I understand it could be easier to do this with class method but I do not want to give up the convenience of scopes being chainable and extensible. What should I do to replace the `with_exclusive_scope` in Rails 4?

Thanks for reading

Comment: This is not the answer to the question, but rather a suggestion. Simply don't use the default_scope. It causes way more headaches over the lifetime of an app than it actually solves. And using rescope or other techniques to remove the previous default relation doesn't seem very DRY.

Comment: Very true indeed. Originally I still opt for default_scope because I think in most situation, that is true. I don't want to require a Post.active for all normal post call. Anyway, seems like that should be the way to go for (Considering there're a lot of changes in scope's syntax thru RoR 3 to 4 to 4.1)

Comment: Actually if `scope` do not merge with `default_scope`'s definition, all problems will be solved! Why would `default_scope` be designed in such way?...

Answer (score 2):

You should use `unscope` of `rescope`. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#overriding-conditions for more information

Comment: Thanks! However, it seems like unscope and rescope can only be used in methods but not at the scope definition part?